# Showing a few popupmenu on one click button in RecyclerView Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I have problem with showing popupmenu. When I clicked on ImageButton , on display shown a few popupmenu(for different elements - in click listener of ClickedPopUpMenu I show toast with position).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Android.App;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using DexpensMobile.Core.Models;
using DexpensMobile.Core.Services;
using DexpensMobile.Core.Services.AuthService;
using DexpensMobile.Droid.Screens;
using UniversalImageLoader.Core;
using UniversalImageLoader.Core.Display;
using PopupMenu = Android.Widget.PopupMenu;

namespace DexpensMobile.Droid.Adapters
{
    public class PostListAdapter :  RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        protected Activity context = null;
        protected IList<PostModel> tasks = new List<PostModel>();
        ImageLoader _imageLoader;
        private int popPosition;
        private int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        private int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

        public PostListAdapter(IList<PostModel> tasks, Activity context)
        {
            this.tasks = tasks;
             _imageLoader = ImageLoader.Instance;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public PostListAdapter() { }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
        {
            if (IsPositionHeader(position))
                return Resource.Layout.wall_header;
            return Resource.Layout.ItemPost;
        }

        private bool IsPositionHeader(int position)
        {
            return position == 0;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            if (holder.GetType() == typeof(PostViewHodler))
            {
                PostViewHodler vh = holder as PostViewHodler;
                var item = tasks[position-1];
                var _userData = ServiceLocator.GetService<IAuthService>().GetUserData();
                vh.ShowPopUpMenuButton.Click += (sender, e) => button_Click(sender, e, position);
                var tempText = item.Text;
                if (tempText.EndsWith("<br/>"))
                    tempText = tempText.Substring(0, tempText.Length - 5);
                tempText = tempText.Replace("<br/>", "\n");
                tempText = Regex.Replace(tempText, @"^\s+$[\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
                vh.PostText.Text = tempText;
                vh.OwnerFullName.Text = item.CreatorName;
                vh.DateText.Text = item.CreatedDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                vh.LikeText.Text = item.Like.LikesCount > 0
                    ? item.Like.LikesCount.ToString()
                    : "";
                vh.CommentText.Text = item.Comments.Any() ? item.Comments.Count().ToString() : "";
                vh.RepostText.Text = item.SharedCount > 0 ? item.SharedCount.ToString() : "";
                var options =
                    new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                        .CacheInMemory(false)
                        .CacheOnDisk(false)
                        .Displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(500))
                        .Build();
                _imageLoader.DisplayImage(item.AvatarUrl, vh.AvatarProfile, options);
            }
            else if (holder.GetType() == typeof(PostViewHodlerHeader))
            {
                PostViewHodlerHeader vh = holder as PostViewHodlerHeader;
                vh.OwnerNameHeader.Text = "Hi from header :-)";
            }
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs, int position)
        {

            ImageButton im = sender as ImageButton;
            PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(im.Context, im);
            menu.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popup_menu);
            //if (item.ApplicationUserId != _userData.UserId)
            //{
            menu.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.editPopUp).SetVisible(false);
            menu.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.deletePopUp).SetVisible(false);
            //}
            menu.Show();
            Toast.MakeText(context, position.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            menu.MenuItemClick += (o, args) => PopUpMenuClickListener(o, args, position);
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemView = null;
            if (viewType == Resource.Layout.wall_header)
            {
                itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.wall_header, parent, false);
                PostViewHodlerHeader vhHeader = new PostViewHodlerHeader(itemView);
                return vhHeader;
            }
            else if(viewType == Resource.Layout.ItemPost)
            {  
                    itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemPost, parent, false);
                    PostViewHodler vhBody = new PostViewHodler(itemView, OnClick, tasks);
                    return vhBody;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void OnClick(int position)
        {
            if (ItemClick != null)
                ItemClick(this, position);
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return tasks.Count +1; }
        }

        private void PopUpMenuClickListener(object sender, PopupMenu.MenuItemClickEventArgs e, int position)
        {
            switch(e.Item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.copyLinkPopUp: 
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.editPopUp:
                    ((WallActivity)context).EditPost(popPosition);
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.deletePopUp:
                    ((WallActivity)context).DeleteItem(popPosition);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class PostViewHodler : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView OwnerFullName { get; private set; }
        public ImageView AvatarProfile { get; private set; }
        public TextView DateText { get; private set; }
        public TextView PostText { get; private set; }
        public TextView LikeText { get; private set; }
        public TextView CommentText { get; private set; }
        public TextView RepostText { get; private set; }
        public ImageButton ShowPopUpMenuButton { get; private set; }

        public PostViewHodler(View itemView, Action<int> listener, IList<PostModel> posts) : base(itemView)
        {
            OwnerFullName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.UserName);
            AvatarProfile = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.postAva);
            DateText = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.dateText);
            PostText = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.postText);
            LikeText = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.likeText);
            CommentText = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.commentText);
            RepostText = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.repostText);
            ShowPopUpMenuButton = itemView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.popupMenuButton);
            itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.Position);
        }
    }

    public class PostViewHodlerHeader : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView OwnerNameHeader{ get; private set; }
        public ImageView AvatarProfileHeader { get; private set; }

        public PostViewHodlerHeader(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            OwnerNameHeader = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.details);
            AvatarProfileHeader = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.avatar_image);
        }
    }
}
```

I think problem bind with recycling elements.
[Video link](https://youtu.be/4v7eirXUCN4) with problem.

How to show only one popupmenu only for current item in recyclerview? Why this problem occur?